# Prove that the equation has a polynomial of degree $n$ as a solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, I need to show that 
$$(1-x^2)y^{''} – xy^{'} + n^2y = 0 $$ 
has a polynomial of degree $n$ as a solution.
I tried the substitution $x = \cos{t}$, which did not give a better expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your substitution $x = \cos{t}$, we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} = -\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\sin{t}} $$
and then
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2} = \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}}{\sin^2{t}} - \frac{\cos{t}\frac{dy}{dt}}{\sin^3{t}}.  $$
On re-substituting back into the original equation, we get something which is much easier to deal with. Try it yourself from this point or continue reading.

> We get $$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} + n^2y = 0. $$
> $y = \cos{nt}$ is a solution to this, which implies that the original equation has a solution $y(x) = \cos{n \arccos{x}}$, which is the $n^{th}$ Chebyshev polynomial: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Just make an ansatz with a polynomial (or formal power series) $y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots$ and use the formal derivatives $y'=a_1+2{a_2}x+3{a_3}x^2+\ldots$ and $y''=2a_2+6{a_3}x+12a_4x^2+\ldots$. Then in degree $k$, the differential equation translates to 
$$ (k+2)(k+1)a_{k+2}-k(k-1)a_k-ka_k+n^2a_k=0.$$
So for $k= n$, we get
$$ \tag1(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}=0$$
and for $k\ne n$, we can solve for $a_k$:
$$\tag2 a_k=\frac{(k+2)(k+1)}{k^2-n^2}\,a_{k+2}.$$
We see that we can let $a_k=0$ for $k>n$, pick $a_n=1$, and define $a_k$ for $0\le k<n$ (backwards) recursively via $(2)$.
Then the resulting polynomial of degree $n$ is apparently a solution to the original differential equation.

We also note that this polynomials is (up to constant factor) the only *polynomial* solution.
There is an independent power series solution obtained by letting $a_k=0$ for all $k\equiv n\pmod 2$, and $a_{n+1}=1$, and applying the recursion $(2)$ in both directions; by the quotient criterion and $(2)$, the radius of convergence for this power series is $1$.